# How to get path of a field of a model dynamically from root to leaf

Tags: java, dynamic

I have one requirement in Java where I have a student object. Let us say I am accessing pin using `studentObj.getAddress().getPin();`.
I want to print the path like address.pin for the pin dynamically without using reflection. In a similar way, I want to get path like address.doorNo for the doorNo. Is it possible?

```java
class Student {
    private Address address;
    private String name;
}

class Address {
    String pin;
    String doorNo;    
}
```

Comment: Please don't add tags to titles, that is what the question tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

The [Apache Commons BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) project is a library capable of that.

Check
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.4/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard.nested

Comment: Thanks for answering but the thing you shared is just to access nested property and  not about getting its full path like address.pin or address.doorNo dynamically.

Comment: True, it works one way only. But just thinking of the bottom-up approach, how would you implement it? After all, a POJO does not necessarily know where in memory there are references to itself.